# Batch file to input multiple file types and segregate them as per file type

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p var=Enter source folder:

set /p var1=Enter destination folder:
set /p var2=Select Filer:

xcopy /f /j /s /z /c /y  "%var%\*.%var2%" "%var1%\%var2%"
```

I have written above batch file, I need it should take multiple filters like HTM, XML etc and paste them in destination folder (create folders same as filter name) and segregate them as per filters.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `for`? type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your batch code extended as requested and commented:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem For source and target folder predefine the variables with
rem a double quote as value to avoid a syntax error in case of
rem user just hits key RETURN or ENTER without entering anything.

:EnterSource
set "SourceFolder=""
set /P "SourceFolder=Enter source folder: "
rem Remove all double quotes from enter string.
set "SourceFolder=!SourceFolder:"=!"
rem Check if the remaining string is an empty string.
if "%SourceFolder%" == "" goto EnterSource
rem Replace all slashes by backslashes
set "SourceFolder=!SourceFolder:/=\!"
rem Remove a trailing backslash.
if "%SourceFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "SourceFolder=!SourceFolder:~0,-1!"
rem Check if source folder exists.
if not exist "%SourceFolder%\*" goto EnterSource
echo.

:EnterTarget
set "TargetFolder=""
set /P "TargetFolder=Enter target folder: "
set "TargetFolder=!TargetFolder:"=!"
if "%TargetFolder%" == "" goto EnterTarget
set "TargetFolder=!TargetFolder:/=\!"
if "%TargetFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "TargetFolder=!TargetFolder:~0,-1!"

echo.
echo Multiple select filter can be entered separated by spaces.
echo.
echo For example: *.txt *.htm *.log
echo.
echo The default is: *
echo.

:EnterFilter
set "SelectFilter=*"
set /P "SelectFilter=Select filter: "
set "SelectFilter=!SelectFilter:"=!"
if "%SelectFilter%" == "" goto EnterFilter

rem Run xcopy for each filter specified. The command FOR is used to separate
rem the string on spaces. Only the first token (= first filer) is always
rem used for a single XCOPY execution and the remaining token (= filters)
rem are assigned again to variable SelectFilter. After each execution of
rem XCOPY it is checked if there are more folters to process and therefore
rem if FOR and XCOPY must be executed once more.

:CopyLoop
for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%SelectFilter%") do (
    call :GetFileType "%%~xI"
    xcopy "%SourceFolder%\%%I" "%TargetFolder%\!FileType!" /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
    set "SelectFilter=%%J"
)
if not "%SelectFilter%" == "" goto CopyLoop
endlocal
goto :EOF

rem This function TRIES to get from file extension string according to
rem filter specification just the file type using string substitutions.
rem The command goto :EOF results in exiting the function an returning
rem to CopyLoop above with continuing the execution on command XCOPY.

:GetFileType
set "FileType=%~1"

rem The passed file type string could be an empty string if the filter
rem specification is for example "File*" without a file extension.

if "%FileType%" == "" goto :EOF

rem Remove the period at beginning of file type string. It is
rem guaranteed that there is only one period in the entire file
rem type string which is at beginning if there is one at all.

set "FileType=%FileType:.=%"

rem The file type string could be now an empty string if the filter
rem specification is for example just "*" to match all files.

if "%FileType%" == "" goto :EOF

rem Remove an asterisk at end of file type string if there is one.

if "%FileType:~-1%" == "*" set "FileType=%FileType:~0,-1%"

rem The file type string could be now an empty string
rem if the filter specification is for example "*.*".

if "%FileType%" == "" goto :EOF

rem Remove everything after first wildcard character
rem for example if filter specification is "*.php?".

for /F "tokens=1 delims=*?" %%T in ("%FileType%") do set "FileType=%%T"
if "%FileType%" == "" goto :EOF

rem Remove all question marks if the file type string
rem consists now only of 1 or more question marks.

set "FileType=%FileType:?=%"

rem The file type string could be now an empty string if
rem the filter specification is for example "Image*.???".

if "%FileType%" == "" goto :EOF

rem Append a backslash to not empty file type string for XCOPY.

set "FileType=%FileType%\"
goto :EOF
```

An example for most difficult task to solve: getting file type from filter specifications:

Source folder is: `C:\Temp\Source`
Target folder is: `C:\Temp\Target`
Select filter is: `* *.* *.txt *.htm* *.php? File* x.y.* File_??.* Image*.???`

The **XCOPY** commands executed are:

```
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\*"          "C:\Temp\Target\"     /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\*.*"        "C:\Temp\Target\"     /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\*.txt"      "C:\Temp\Target\txt"  /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\*.htm*"     "C:\Temp\Target\htm\" /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\*.php?"     "C:\Temp\Target\php\" /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\File*"      "C:\Temp\Target\"     /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\x.y.*"      "C:\Temp\Target\"     /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\File_??.*"  "C:\Temp\Target\"     /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
xcopy "C:\Temp\Source\Image*.???" "C:\Temp\Target\"     /C /F /H /I /K /R /S /Y
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Comment: This is really really helpful thanks a lot, Just one thing it doesn't create separate folders same as filter name and segregate them in it.

Comment: @Sandy Batch code reworked for determining file type from filter specification and append it to target folder path. An example in question with input and output directory listing would have been good to understand this requirement. It would have been also useful to describe what the batch code should expect as filter specification. The code is written for even unusual filter specifications, but I'm quite sure it is not working for all filters a batch user can input.